# write within R function a latex chunk using knitR

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown, sweave

I have the following problem; I use knitR within Rstudio to generate pdf. In the main file which is called: "`master.Rnw`"  I call a long function called "`trigono.R`" :

```
<<trigono_R, echo=FALSE, warning=FALSE, cache=FALSE, eval=TRUE>>=

source("./trigono.R")  
@
```

now the question: is there any possibility to call within this R function a latex-chunk. That means within the following function:

```
trigono<- function(con = con, run.type = NULL){

normal R commands

open chunk Latex(

end chunk Latex)

normal R commands
}
```

have a Latex command or leave the R chunk `<<... >>=  ...  @` and go back into Latex to write some sentences.

thanks a lot

Comment: Smells like a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What do you want to *achieve*?

Comment: ok I do not know if it is a XY problem :) but there is a possibility to solve it and that is to use  [child in knitR](http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/child/) but here I am looking for another solution which might be easier to implement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found by myself the answer and give it here although  I cannot understand why I earned negative vote sometimes here is really frustrating!

At first one needs 2 libraries:

library(knitr)

library(printr)

you must use a child which contains your function. Let say within `master.Rnw` you call a child named `trigono.Rnw`

```
<<childIntroduc, child='trigono.Rnw',results = "asis">>=
@
```

`trigono.Rnw` looks like:

```
<< myfunctions, echo=FALSE, eval=TRUE>>=
normal R commands

.
.
cat(" \\newline \\emph{The text which appears as a normal text in Latex and Pdf \\color{red} 2.5.6} \\newline")
.
.
@
```